# Moto G 3rd generation only savings contacts info locally - not showing up on contacts.google.com

Tags: contacts, sync, motorola-moto-g, google-contacts

I was saving contact notes on the contacts app of the Moto G 3rd generation.

I haven't checked the desktop https://contacts.google.com/preview/all in a while, and when I went there, I found that my contact notes wasn't being saved.

It remained local to the Moto G.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the .vcf from Moto G to Google Drive.

Importing a .vcf wasn't available yet for the new Google Contacts (contacts.google.com), so they showed steps to go to the old Google Contacts.

After importing, I merged to get rid of the duplicates.

After doing this, changes on Moto G were reflected on the desktop https://contacts.google.com/preview/all, and other mobile devices.

I don't think I changed any sync settings on the Moto G to get it to work, but it's possible that something else solved the problem, instead of importing from Moto G to the desktop Google Contacts.